# DOM Parser in Javascript (testing without using a web server)

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'm trying to parse a simple xml document using a DOM parser in JS, but the parser can't load the file. I'm using the examples from a *popular website* and I thought this would work.

All my files are store on my local compter (not using a web server... using file:/// and not http:// ).

my code is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","chinese.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;

x=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
document.write(x[i].nodeName);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

both my hmtl and xml files are located in the same folder. I can't understand why this is not working

xml file is

```
<!DOCTYPE menu SYSTEM "chinese.dtd">
<menu>
  <dish>
     <name>Chicken Sweetcorn Soup</name>
     <price>1.60</price>
   </dish>
  <dish>
    <name>Spring Roll</name>
    <price>1.50</price>
  </dish>
  <dish>
    <name>Special Satay</name>
    <ingredients>King Prawn, Chicken, Beef with Vegetables</ingredients>
    <price>4.50</price>
  </dish>
  <dish>
    <name>Barbecued Spare Ribs</name>
    <price>3.99</price>
  </dish>
  <dish>
    <name>Sweet and Sour Pork</name>
    <style>Cantonese</style>
    <price>4.49</price>
  </dish>
</menu>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to parse anything here.  If you're working from the local filesystem, then it may be that your browser is preventing the XHR from running because it doesn't consider your local filesystem to be trusted.

Comment: @R.S maybe IE has nothing to do with this ... that code would do the same thing in any browser

Comment: yes I think the same. I believe I'missing something very basic, but I'm new to DOM and I can't see what this is.I'm using chrome by the way

Comment: Could you also add a sample of the xml

Comment: Please try my code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers (except Firefox, as far as I know) don't support loading local XML files stored on your computer (i.e. files that are not provided using a web server) with AJAX due to security reasons. So if you tested your script locally (using `file:///`) in Chrome, it will not work.

Just use Firefox to test your script or upload it to a server (I'd recommend using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)).

Comment: Could you read my post and try the example @ http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_parsertest using the sample code at the bottom of my post in chrome and tell me if it does NOT work and if you are the .. that down vote me plz add it back

Comment: Obviously your example won't work in Chrome (when not executed on a server) as it also tries to load local XML files. I downvoted your answer as it doesn't provide a solution to the question and might confuse others.

Comment: @Aletheios... your right it will not work without a webserver. but where in question did they mention (or the 10 edits before that i was working from) that this was not running on a web server but instead on their local computer?

Comment: I just read "the parser can't load the file" in the question and immediately remembered that I once had the same problem in a project of mine. So I guessed that the script was run on a local computer.

Comment: @Aletheios... instead of just "down voting" answer, you may want to consider taking a minute to explain your reasoning. The original question just stated that .... xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML doesn't load; without providing any loop structure to display the result. As the question evolved, I updated my answer accordingly with example on how to test. So it was upto the person asking the question to realize that this code does work (but not on their local computer) and explain that the code is on their local computer without a web server. If you look at the comment below my answer they finally did.

Comment: I voted down the 4th or 5th revision of your answer. Although it didn't help @mariosk89 that much, your final answer is better. Maybe you could consider undoing your down vote on my answer now (assuming it was you).